# C# Source code generator dependent on existing class

Tags: c#, code-generation

I need to generate source code that will inherit from an abstract class that I already have present in my project, and the source generator project itself compiles. But when the compiler complains that the generated sources does not recognize the abstract class, even though its in the same project. Do I need to tell the generator project to have runtime dependencies to itself in some way?

EDIT:
Im using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp. Here is the code describing the sitation:
https://github.com/alebo611/csharpsourcegenproblem/tree/main/MyGeneratorProject

That is, I just want to generate a subclass of the already defined "Vehicle". If you run it in Visual Studio, you will get following error:

Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'Vehicle' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   Consumer generated.cs

And adding "Using ApplicationContext" does not help, it will complain it does not find the context.

Comment: Do you have the namespace imported in the generated class? Can you edit your question and add the generated code along with the abstract class you want to inherit?

Comment: It would be great if you could posted full repro. At least can you please add the error itself?

Comment: Are you missing a Using statement.

Comment: What code generation are you using? If you are using CodeDOM and compiling in memory, you need to tell the compiler where to look for all the references in the program by calling `CompilerParameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add()` for each one.

Comment: Thanks for the interest. I have posted a github repo with a small example describing my problem, see edit.

Comment: Did you do step 7 in [these instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/source-generators-overview)?

Comment: You set `ReferenceOutputAssembly="false"`, which means that the `Vehicle` class of the source generator project is not referenced in the consumer project. Try omitting it or setting it to `true`.

Comment: @pschill Thanks, that was the problem of course. I removed the referencedOutputAssembly parameter and now it works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Source generators are used to generate new source code that will then be compiled and added to your assembly. This means that usually, the source generator assembly is only required at build time. Therefore, when consuming a source generator via `ProjectReference`, you usually use `OutputItemType="Analyzer"` and `ReferenceOutputAssembly="false"`:

```
<ProjectReference Include="SourceGenerator.csproj"
                  OutputItemType="Analyzer"
                  ReferenceOutputAssembly="false" />
```

In your example however, the source generator assembly contains a type `Vehicle` that is required by the consuming assembly. This means that the source generator assembly must be referenced by the consumer, so you must omit the `ReferenceOutputAssembly` parameter:

```
<ProjectReference Include="SourceGenerator.csproj"
                  OutputItemType="Analyzer" />
```

It is unfortunate that the consumer must take care of such details of the generator. Fortunately, things are different when consuming the source generator via package. In that case, the package author takes care that assemblies required at build time are stored in `analyzers/dotnet/cs` within the package and assemblies that are required at runtime are stored in `lib/[targetframework]`.